# Are there extensions for addition rules automation

Tags: workflow, rules

For example, if I need to notify a specific user when a work item is created, I don't see an action to notify a specific user or groups, are there extensions out there in the market place to achieve this?
Thanks.

I don't see any extensions in the market place.